# NodeJS get value from Promise

Tags: node.js

I'm try to get value from external method that is a promise. 
Logger.info() work fine and print when error is or not.
 but how can I return a value to use in my indexController?

this is code:

```
// indexController

    async function version() {
      await DB.healthCheck().then(value => {
        console.log(value);
      });
    }

//DB.healthCheck() File

let mysql = require('mysql');

async function healthCheck() {
  var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'HOST',
    user: 'USERNAME',
    password: 'XXXXX',
    database: 'DATABSE',
  });

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    connection.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        logger.info('DB connection: KO');
        return reject(0);
      }
      logger.info('DB connection: OK');
      return resolve(1);
    });
  });
}

module.exports = { healthCheck };
```

Comment: Not related to your question, but you might want to look into using the `mysql2` npm package, and import/require it using `'mysql2/promise'` to get proper async/await-able code as well. It becomes much nicer to work with IMHO. 

Or you can mutate all the mysql functions with `util.promisify` which is builtin with node.js, before using them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to return the value from `version` and still log it, you can do so like this.

```
async function version() {
  const value = await DB.healthCheck();
  console.log(value);
  return value;
}
```

---

**What follows below is not recommended**, but for you to use your previous style of mixing `await` and `then`, you would have had to return a value from your `.then` clause, and returned the value you awaited.  I show this only so that you understand what you were missing.  Although this technically works, most people will frown on this as a matter of poor style, so please go with my first suggestion.

```
async function version() {
  return await DB.healthCheck().then(value => {
    console.log(value);
    return value;
  });
}
```